# Displaying MAX() with other columns getting error without group by statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to get my SQL statement to show the max total weight lifted side by side with the corresponding exercise description however it will not work without a `GROUP BY` statement.

Here is the code :

```
SELECT e.exercisedescription, MAX(oe.rep*oe.attempt_1*oe.attempt_2*oe.attempt_3) AS max_reps
FROM occurance_exercise oe, exercise e
WHERE oe.exerciseno = e.exerciseno
GROUP BY e.exercisedescription 
ORDER BY MAX(oe.rep*oe.attempt_1*oe.attempt_2*oe.attempt_3) DESC;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join on the result of the aggregation:

```
SELECT e.*, oe.max_reps
FROM exercise e  
  JOIN (
    SELECT ex.exerciseno, max(ex.rep * ex.attempt_1 * ex.attempt_2 * ex.attempt_3) AS max_reps
    FROM occurance_exercise ex
    GROUP BY ex.exerciseno
  ) oe ON oe.exerciseno = e.exerciseno
ORDER BY oe2.max_reps DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the maximum weight lifted per exercise, the query in question is correct only. Use of an aggregate like **Max** requires a **Group By** clause if there are any *non-aggregated* columns in the select list.
If you want to show the maximum weight lifted out of all the exercises, you should use something like below:

```
SELECT e.exercisedescription, oe.rep*oe.attempt_1*oe.attempt_2*oe.attempt_3 AS max_reps
FROM occurance_exercise oe, exercise e
WHERE oe.exerciseno = e.exerciseno
AND oe.rep*oe.attempt_1*oe.attempt_2*oe.attempt_3 = (
SELECT MAX(oe.rep*oe.attempt_1*oe.attempt_2*oe.attempt_3
FROM occurance_exercise oe, exercise e
WHERE oe.exerciseno = e.exerciseno);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want one row with the maximum.  If so, you don't want aggregation, you want filtering . . . in this case after ordering:

```
SELECT e.exercisedescription,  
       (oe.rep * oe.attempt_1 * oe.attempt_2 * oe.attempt_3) AS max_reps
FROM occurance_exercise oe JOIN
     exercise e
     ON oe.exerciseno = e.exerciseno
ORDER BY max_reps DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note:  Not all databases use `LIMIT`.  In fact, the standard syntax is `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`.  Some use `SELECT TOP` or something else.

Also, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.